# Where do I find the Statistics module?

Tags: nodes, 5

I must use Drupal 5.10 for one project. It's already done, but I am doing some changes, so I must add this line to each node:

> Viewed: 3 | Total views: 30

I know I must use the Statistics module, but I cannot find one for Drupal 5. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Drupal 5 is SO far out of support now you're not likely to turn much up.  However, it does look like `statistics.module` [was in core back then](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/tree/refs/heads/5.x:/modules/statistics), so you might be able to find some deprecated documentation.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search turned up this video from DrupalDude: [Statistics module in Drupal 5](http://www.drupaldude.com/content/statistics-module-drupal-5)

There's also the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/5) for the module for the D5 version on Drupal.org that suggests you should be able to use `statistics_get()` to get the views for a certain node.

*Something* like the following would do it:

```
$stats = statistics_get($nid);

// Total view count
print $stats['totalcount'];
// Current day view count    
print $stats['daycount'];
// Timestamp of last view
print $stats['timestamp'];
```